# Asset Subdirectories in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a Rails 3.1 app with an image:

```
app/assets/images/icons/button.png
```

It seems like the image should be served at this URL:

```
assets/icons/button.png
```

but if I go to this URL I get a 404. To fix this I created an initializer and added my `images/icons` subdirectory to the asset path:

```
Rails.application.assets.append_path "app/assets/images/icons"
```

However, this does not seem like it can possibly be the recommended way to accomplish this. I'm aware of the `require` and `require_tree` directives for JavaScript and CSS assets, is there an equivalent for image assets? How are other people doing this?

Comment: Where do you want to use your images? In the [Asset Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), I find the following code: `image_tag "icons/rails.png"`.

Comment: If you omit the `image_tag` call it probably won't package your asset properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **EDIT: As of Rails 3.2.rc1 this is now fixed! asset_path now generates proper paths when deploying to sub-uri!**

For images it **just** works. Rails packages everything in images/ tree. I personally use them like this (actual code):

CSS:

```
a#icon-followers{
  background:  url(<%= asset_data_uri "icons/followers.png" %>) center center no-repeat;
}
```

(`asset_data_uri` actually makes the images inline in the CSS file using base64, but that's irrelevant in this case)

No custom configuration required. After precompiling, images from `app/assets/icons/` end up in `public/assets/icons/`.

You can open `public/assets/manifest.yml` to see how Rails translates the paths to actual files.